# ¿Cómo se pueden poner dos etiquetas distintas de img?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un fichero html con imágenes, y quiero que un grupo de ellas se comporten de una forma y el otro grupo de distinta forma.
Las primeras están centradas en un slider. Y quedan de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene el código CSS

```
img {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:relative;
}
```

El problema es que este código CSS también afecta al siguiente grupo de imágenes. Estas aparecen desplazadas hacia la derecha en lugar de estar centradas con el texto.
[image: Imágenes desplazadas debido a CSS anterior]

Si modifico la etiqueta  de las primeras imágenes, el segundo grupo de imágenes se centra automáticamente, pero pierden su centro las superiores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta segunda forma dejo el código CSS así:

```
img1 {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:relative;
}
```

E inserto las imágenes en el slider (las que ahora no están centradas y se salen del contenedor) de la siguiente forma;

```
<div class="img1"><img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/coronavirus-covid19-or-ncov-outbreak-banner-concept-design-vector-id1213834466?k=6&m=1213834466&s=170667a&w=0&h=WZWKijVyXW93QKF4zz8Qyu3_yhp3yAaBcE_2-FPrcTw=" width="900px" height="150">
      </div>
```

Me parece que la forma de solucionarlo es tener una etiqueta img para las imágenes superiores y otra etiqueta img independiente para las inferiores, de forma que entre sí no se influyan y puedan funcionar por separado. El problema es que no sé cómo se podría hacer esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Me parece que la forma de solucionarlo es tener una etiqueta img para las imágenes superiores y otra etiqueta img independiente para las inferiores

Estás en lo cierto, lo único que en vez de jugar con 2 etiquetas, deberías usar 2 clases.

Lo que propones de:

```
<div class="img1"><img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/coronavirus-covid19-or-ncov-outbreak-banner-concept-design-vector-id1213834466?k=6&m=1213834466&s=170667a&w=0&h=WZWKijVyXW93QKF4zz8Qyu3_yhp3yAaBcE_2-FPrcTw=" width="900px" height="150">
      </div>
```

realmente lo puedes simplicar y poner la class dentro del img:

```
<img class="img1" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/coronavirus-covid19-or-ncov-outbreak-banner-concept-design-vector-id1213834466?k=6&m=1213834466&s=170667a&w=0&h=WZWKijVyXW93QKF4zz8Qyu3_yhp3yAaBcE_2-FPrcTw=" width="900px" height="150">
```

Con esto, definirías tu css con 2 clases: img1 y img2. Aunque yo le daría otros nombres que fueran mas intuitivos: img_slider y img_stats (por ejemplo):

```
.img_slider {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:relative;
}
.img_stats {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:relative;
}
```

Al usar el punto antes del nombre, css sabe que estás hablando de una class.

OJO: el css que he pegado en mi respuesta para las dos clases es el tuyo, lo tendrías que adaptar con los cambios que comentabas al inicio de tu publicación.

Comment: Muchísismas gracias! Ya lo he solucionado!

Answer (score 1):

Al menos a como explicas lo que te ocurre:

- Los estilos afectan a todas tus imágenes por que estás haciendo un selector de tipo, al utilizar la etiqueta img, entonces todas aquellas que empaten se verán modificadas
- Si buscas tener 2 grupos de imágenes y que en concencuencia cada grupo de estos tengan estilos propios deberás entonces hacer uso de un selector de clase `.clase`

Es decir, tener una estructura similar a esta:

```
  <img src="" alt="" class="grupoUno">
  <img src="" alt="" class="grupoUno">
  <img src="" alt="" class="grupoUno">
  <img src="" alt="" class="grupoUno">
  <img src="" alt="" class="grupoUno">
  
  <img src="" alt="" class="grupoDos">
  <img src="" alt="" class="grupoDos">
  <img src="" alt="" class="grupoDos">
  <img src="" alt="" class="grupoDos">
  <img src="" alt="" class="grupoDos">
```

Entonces:

- La regla CSS que construyas para `.grupoUno` de ninguna forma afectará al segundo grupo y solo estilizará a las primeras 5 imágenes.

---

```
.grupoUno {
  /*CSS para las primeras 5 imágenes*/
}


.grupoDos {
    /*CSS para las últimas 5 imágenes*/
}
```

Te recomiendo [leas mas sobre selectores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_CSS)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Gracias a esto ya lo he solucionado

Answer (score 1):

Crear etiquetas diferentes, no es recomendable, en realidad es una mala practica y no deberias hacerlo.

Me refiero a por ejemplo crear una etiqueta "img" y luego otra "img2", eso esta mal, las etiquetas son las que se encuentran en la documentacion de HTML.

Por otro parte lo que te recomiendo es que utilices "clases", las clases permiten agrupar o identificar uno o muchos elementos por ende poder aplicarle estilos a grupos especificos.

Es decir yo tengo 2 span que quiero que se vean subrayados y otros 2 que solo se vean rojos sin subrayado.

Lo que deberias realizar es lo siguiente

```
<span class="subrayado">Texto Subrayado</span>
<span class="subrayado">Otro Subrayado</span>
<span class="rojo">Texto en color rojo</span>
<span class="rojo">Mas texto en color rojo</span>
```

Ahi si te fijas utilice el atributo llamado "class", el cual te menciono arriba y ahora en css puedes darle estio a esos grupos

```
.subrayado{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.rojo{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! También lo he conseguido solucionar gracias a tu comentario